# Live Domains - email marked as spam

Tags: email, domain, spam-prevention, windows-live-mail

I'm using Domains Live for my domain as email service provider. However, those emails I send are usually marked as spam...

I have set the MX record to **Prove domain ownership** and TXT record of **Server trust** as Microsoft suggested in the Domains Live administration. What can I do more? Thanks.

Comment: What email providers are marking your email as spam?

Comment: They are various providers but the large one is for example Seznam.cz. The problem is that I just can't contact every provider to whitelist my domain... With Google Apps I had no problem.

Comment: If you contact one they might be able to tell you why its being flagged as spam.  Is there any chance your domain is simply blacklisted as spam?

Comment: No, it can't be blacklisted as spam. My domain is kind of new and there were no emails send that are of spam-type. I'll try to contact that provider if they can give me some info...